# php usort objects is returning unexpected order

Tags: php, usort

The following should sort an array of Drivers by ascending lap time:

```
function sortDrivers($a, $b)
{
  if (floatval($a->fastestLap) === floatval($b->fastestLap)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return floatval($a->fastestLap) < floatval($b->fastestLap) ? -1 : 1;
}

Log::info("Before:");
foreach($drivers as &$driver){
  Log::info($driver->driverCode . " - " . floatval($driver->fastestLap));
}

usort($drivers, "sortDrivers");

$position = 0;
foreach($drivers as &$driver){
  $driver->position = ++$position;
  $driver->save();
}

Log::info("After:");
foreach($drivers as &$driver){
  Log::info($driver->driverCode . " - " . floatval($driver->fastestLap) . " - " . $driver->position);
}
```

The actual output from this looks something like:

```
Before:  
Mark - 112.2  
Roger - 108.77  
Pete - 110.038  
Gary - 109.49  
Sid - 111.742  
Rod - 87.082  
Bob - 110.404  
Eric - 112.482  
Will - 113.478  
Nigel - 0  
Harry - 110.01  
Paul - 112.887  
Victor - 109.182  
Matt - 109.987  
Clive - 109.975  
Sol - 109.23  
Olly - 0  
Ben - 0  
Craig - 114.241  
Andy - 96.399  
Adam - 93.177  
Kel - 110.766  

After:  
Rod - 87.082 - 1  
Adam - 93.177 - 2  
Paul - 112.887 - 3  
Roger - 108.77 - 4  
Bob - 110.404 - 5  
Mark - 112.2 - 6  
Will - 113.478 - 7  
Gary - 109.49 - 8  
Pete - 110.038 - 9  
Harry - 110.01 - 10  
Matt - 109.987 - 11  
Craig - 114.241 - 12  
Eric - 112.482 - 13  
Sid - 111.742 - 14  
Kel - 110.766 - 15  
Clive - 109.975 - 16  
Sol - 109.23 - 17  
Victor - 109.182 - 18  
Andy - 96.399 - 19  
Olly - 0 - 20  
Nigel - 0 - 21  
Ben - 0 - 22
```

While there's clearly some trend towards increasing lap time, several drivers are in the wrong place.

Why?

Comment: `floatval($a->fastestLap) === floatval($b->fastestLap)` is a loosing bet. Never expect two floating point values to be equal. Compare the absolute value of their difference against a small threshold and consider them equal when the threshold is not exceeded. However, this is not the cause of the behaviour you exposed here.

Comment: I cannot duplicate your behaviour with your 'sortDrivers' function - it works ;-/ Whatever, here is something that seems to do what you want: https://eval.in/643912. i.e .zero times sort last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies. I was using the wrong sort function, not the one posted above.